# How can I get the count of multiple table rows storing in different variables using single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, google-bigquery

I have 4 different tables and I want to get the count rows of each tables and get the count(*) on 4 different variables.

The query that I have used is:

```
 SELECT count(*) as count1 FROM `table1` 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT count(*) as count2 FROM `table2`
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT count(*) as count3 FROM `table3`
 UNION ALL
 SELECT count(*) as count4 FROM `table4`
```

The query gives me the count of each rows but all the value gets stored on the same variable name.

```
 [
  {
    "count1": 16171
  }, 
  {
    "count1": 5928
  }, 
  {
    "count1": 33318
  }, 
  {
    "count1": 5877
  }
 ]
```

Is there any way i could get the output as;

```
 [
  {
    "count1": 16171
  }, 
  {
    "count2": 5928
  }, 
  {
    "count3": 33318
  }, 
  {
    "count4": 5877
  }
 ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT count(*), 'count1' FROM `table1`` etc

Comment: Thanks worked for me.

Comment: How efficient is the query gonna be? Is there any alternative query that i can use for making the query much more efficient in Big Query.

Comment: I can't figure out any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION ALL` unions rows. It sounds like you just want to list each of the counts in the select list. Try this:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table1`) AS count1,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table2`) AS count2,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table3`) AS count3,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table4`) AS count4
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  table_id,
  row_count
FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.__TABLES__`   
WHERE table_id in ('table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4')
```

This approach allows you to get (for free!!) much more than just rows count - see example below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT table_id,
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time)) AS creation_date,
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time)) AS last_modified_date,
  row_count,
  size_bytes,
  CASE
    WHEN type = 1 THEN 'table'
    WHEN type = 2 THEN 'view'
    WHEN type = 3 THEN 'external'
    ELSE '?'
  END AS type,
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time,
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time,
  dataset_id,
  project_id
FROM `bigquery-public-data.baseball.__TABLES__`
```